# Property functions in Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, jena, virtuoso

I am working with Jena and Virtuoso to host some RDF data.
I am planning to have Jena as the interface and Virtuoso as the backend storage, since Jena seems to be easier to extend and Virtuoso have some nice features such as conversion of relational data into RDF.
My problem is that the property functions that are in Jena (described [here](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/extension.html#property-functions)), and the ones that I want to implement, does not seem to have any effect when virtuoso is used as the underlying storage.

Example of query working when using TDB (TDBFactory.createDataset) to make a dataset but not working when using Virtuoso (VirtGraph, VirtDataset, and also tried QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService):

```
PREFIX  apf:  <java:com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.pfunction.library.>
SELECT  *
WHERE
    { ?s apf:str "Test" }
LIMIT   5
```

I am looking for a way to make Jena/ARQ pre- or post process the results of a query sent to Virtuoso.

If that is not possible, please point in alternative directions. Implementing property function in Virtuoso or use Sesame or other easily extendable system instead are my own initial thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Jena-functionality, then you could issue a query to Virtuoso and return a graph, then execute a query locally on that graph.  Otherwise, youu need the functionality in the server, not the client.

(The `apf:str` functionality is better done nowadays as `FILTER` or `BIND` and `STR()`)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could execute this query against Virtuoso server also, without rewriting.
Try the next:

```
Model m = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel(...);
Query query = QueryFactory.create(
    "PREFIX  apf:  <java:com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.pfunction.library.> "+
    "SELECT  * WHERE { ?s apf:str "Test" } LIMIT   5") ;

QueryExecution qexec = com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, m) ;
ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect() ;
```

The sample above will execute query via Jena ARQ(on client side, but the graph data will be loaded from Virtuoso via VirtosoGraph API calls). 
It will work slower, than server side execution of queries, but you will be able to use all ARQ features.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The code snippet does not provide any results for me. If I use {?S ?P ?O} as triple pattern instead I do get results, so it not the not connection or something like that.